# Animation BottomNavigationView doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

When I click on BottomNavigationView item it doesn't animate on some version (for example Marshallow)

**The expect behavior is**:

*When I click on item the icon become larger and appear the text.*

**But the result is**:

*Icon stay in normal size and appear the text*


**The code**:

build.gradle (app)

```
//AndroidX UI
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
```

activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/activity_home_custombottombar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="@color/app_black"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_bottombar_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_bottombar_item"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_items" />
```

menu_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_action_1" />

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_action_2" />

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_action_3" />

</menu>
```

nav_bottombar_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/app_white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/app_black" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

HomeActivity.kt

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_1 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_1)
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_2 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_2)
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_3 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_3)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

**I expect and result:**

If you can see in the next image the animation doesn't work properly.
I expect something like this:
[image: Spect 1]

[image: Spect 2]

But I obtain this result:
[image: Result]

**UPDATED:**

I just need to call the requestLayout on setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.
Apparently the BottomNavigationView remains blocked, and it just need to redraw.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
bottomNavigationView.requestLayout()
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_1 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_1)
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_2 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_2)
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_3 -> {
                    viewModel.navigationHandler?.switchStack(PredefinedStacks.STACK_ACTION_3)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

Comment: please try `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" `

Comment: if I add labelVisibilityMode="labeled" the labels is showing all the time and I don't want that.

Comment: `android:background="@color/app_black"` what do you think this line does, if not making the entire thing black

Comment: I want the black background if I remove the background the behavior is the same.<br />
Expect behavior:<br />
When I click on item the icon become larger and appear the text.
Error result: <br />
Icon stay in normal size and appear the text.

Answer (score 0):

make these changes to your `nav_bottombar_item.xml` for `app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_bottombar_item"`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/app_white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/app_black" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

and add this `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` also.

Comment: With this code I obtain: https://i.ibb.co/71JHBcg/result.png
and the expect behavior is: When I click on item the icon become larger and appear the text. But i obtain the error result: <br /> Icon stay in normal size and appear the text